# Django Models: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

My application is developed using Python3, Django and PostgreSQL.

When I tried to execute the following query

```
select * from question where question similar to '%(General|ledger)%' and project_id =1
```

I'm getting the error

> TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

I'm executing the query in following way.

```
questions = Question.objects.raw(sql_query.format(query, projectId)) 

serializer = QuestionSerializer(list(questions), many=True)
```

Any help in resolving following issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: Double-up your %s, i.e. `%%(General|ledger)%%`. Note that `sql_query.format(...)` looks vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: thanks @Alasdair. It worked. A couple of more help needed. 1. As of now, this query is case sensitive. Is there a way I can make it case insensitive? 2. How can make the SQL query not vulnerable?

Comment: See the docs on [passing parameters into raw](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw). I don't know how to make `SIMILAR TO` case insensitive. You could rewrite it to use regexes or use `ILIKE` with `or`.

Comment: Thanks again. I rewrote the query as `select * from question where question ~* '({})' and project_id = {}` instead of `similar to` to make it case insensitive.

Comment: You're still using `{}` and `.format()` which is vulnerable. Use `%s` and params like in the link above.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks for pointing out the vulnerability. I followed the instructions given in the document.